# Bootstrap and MathJax single line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mathjax

I am ussing Bootstrap 4 and MathJax. Adding a MathJax formula to a `span` element creates an unwanted new line [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jasdefer/ouqyvcxt/):

`<span class="input-group-addon">Variable \( x_1 \)</span>`

I tried adding `display: block;` to the `span` element. Everything is one single line but the `span` element is not connected correctly to its neighbor.

I want to have a single line `span` element, which is attached correctly.

Comment: Set `.input-group-addon` to have `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for this

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<p>
  Regular:
</p>
 <div class="input-group">
 
      <span class="input-group-addon">Variable \( x_1 \)</span>
       <span class="input-group-btn">
        <select class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
         
        </select>
      </span>
    
      
    </div>
```

check this Fiddle also [Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ouqyvcxt/3/)